# Marketing cloud Exceed 1 million

Tags: journeybuilder

A Journey Builder query was established to select contacts on every Sales Order line.  We loaded 1.1 million Sales Order lines but have now deleted them back to about 35,000 lines.  Marketing Cloud sync’d the contacts and they are still active in Marketing Cloud.

Does anyone know why Marketing Cloud did not delete these sales Order Line ?

Comment: Are you deleting these in CRM and still seeing the records in Synchronized Data Extensions?

Comment: @JacksonChen it resolved now. I did the bulk deletion.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting a record in sales cloud will not delete the contact in SFMC. You would need to use the [contact delete](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_cab_contact_deletion.htm&type=5) process to delete the record within SFMC